# Updating a Zendesk ticket using Python

Tags: python, api, zendesk

After looking (and not finding) any example of updating a ticket in Zendesk using Python, I tried working from the cURL angle
having the exampled cURL :

```
curl https://{subdomain}.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/{id}.json -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"ticket": {"status": "open", "comment": { "body": "The smoke is very colorful.", "author_id": 494820284 }}}' -v -u {email_address}:{password} -X PUT
```

i gave it a few trials and got to a working example:

```
ticket_id = 'number'
output_string = somestring
user = '<user>'
pwd = '<pw>'
url = 'https://{subdomain}.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/' + ticket_id + '.json'
cr_data = '{"ticket": {"status": "pending", "comment": { "body": "' + output_string + '", "author_id": 494820284 }}}'

response = requests.put(url, headers=headers, data=cr_data, auth=(user, pwd))
```

thought it would be a good example for all who seek something like that.

Comment: It isn't really a question...

Comment: @machnic true - its a solution to a problem. i've been looking for this solution for some time here, but haven't found any, so I thought i'd add it for others.